# How do you instantiate a class that calls another instantiation of itself?

Tags: java, instantiation

I am trying to code a rubiks cube and I want to have six Face classes for each face of the cube. In the class I need access to the faces on all four sides of it in order to move the cube correctly so I tried to have four other Face objects in the constructor of a Face. I am wondering if this instantiation would work. Here is how I did it(The first chunk of code is in the main class and the second chunk is from the Face class):

```
white = new Face(red, blue, green, orange, Color.WHITE);
yellow = new Face(orange, blue, green, red, Color.YELLOW);
red = new Face(yellow, blue, green, white, Color.RED);
orange = new Face(white, blue, green, yellow, Color.ORANGE);
blue = new Face(red, yellow, white, orange, Color.BLUE);
green = new Face(red, white, yellow, orange, Color.GREEN);
front = yellow;



public Face top, left, right, bottom;
public Cell[][] cells;

public Face(Face t, Face l, Face r, Face b, Color c) {
    top = t;
    left = l;
    right = r;
    bottom = b;
    cells = new Cell[3][3];
    for(int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
        for(int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
            cells[row][col] = new Cell(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can initialise a `Face` without neighbouring faces first. Then, after all of them are initialised, you define relationships between them by setters.

```
class Face {
  Face white = new Face(Color.WHITE);
  Face yellow = new Face(Color.YELLOW);

  {
    white.setRight(yellow);
    yellow.setLeft(white);
  }


  public Face top, left, right, bottom;
  public Cell[][] cells;

  public Face(Color c) {
    // only cells init
  }

  public void setLeft(Face left) {
    this.left = left;
  }

  public void setRight(Face right) {
    this.right = right;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do is add an initialization function which is used after all objects are instantiated and move the code that needs other instances there. That way you already have valid references when your code is called:

```
    // Instantiate the objects:
    white = new Face(Color.WHITE);
    yellow = new Face(Color.YELLOW);
    red = new Face(Color.RED);
    orange = new Face(Color.ORANGE);
    blue = new Face(Color.BLUE);
    green = new Face(Color.GREEN);
    // Initialize the objects:
    white.intitializeFace(red, blue, green, orange);
    yellow.intitializeFace(orange, blue, green, red);
    red.intitializeFace(yellow, blue, green, white);
    orange.intitializeFace(white, blue, green, yellow);
    blue.intitializeFace(red, yellow, white, orange);
    green.intitializeFace(red, white, yellow, orange);

    front = yellow;
```

```
    public Face(Color c) {
        cells = new Cell[3][3];
        for(int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
            for(int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
                cells[row][col] = new Cell(c);
            }
        }
    }
    public void intitializeFace(Face t, Face l, Face r, Face b) {
        top = t;
        left = l;
        right = r;
        bottom = b;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This example would not work because you cannot reference objects before they're instantiated unless they have been declared with some state.

That being said, if you have another object, lets say, Block, that contained 4 face object, this would solve your problem. A Face could just be composed of the Color and the Block could manage all the logic.

```java
enum Face {
    WHITE(Color.WHITE),
    RED(Color.RED),
    BLUE(Color.BLUE)
    // other elements
    // constructor
    // getters
}
```

```java
class Block {

    // class members

    // cells

    public Block(Face top, Face left, Face right, Face bottom) {
        // assignment
    }

}
```